# How to redirect an assembly binding from a wild carded version to a wild carded version?

Tags: .net, assemblies, versioning, redirect

I know we can do this

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly1" publicKeyToken="3484e1fc2d0c223b" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.99.99.99" newVersion="6.0.3.2"/>
   </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

but i can't seem to do this

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly1" publicKeyToken="3484e1fc2d0c223b" culture="neutral"/>
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.99.99.99" newVersion="6.0.3.0-999"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is supported, per latest .NET 4 doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx

Comment: This isnt supported - why would you want to do this (i.e. what behavior would you expect here)?
The newVersion needs to be an explicit version, stating to the runtime what DLL needs to be loaded, If you have 6.0.3.0 and 6.0.4.0, what would the runtime be expected to do?

Comment: @Adam you should escallate your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isnt supported - why would you want to do this (i.e. what behavior would you expect here)?
The `newVersion` needs to be an explicit version, stating to the runtime what DLL needs to be loaded, If you have 6.0.3.0 and 6.0.4.0, what would the runtime be expected to do?